# Texture scaling faulty when width is uneven

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, scaling

I'm trying to get multiple textures to appear pixel-for-pixel in a GLFW window. How I'm doing it is I have a shared shader that takes a uniform matrix that scales and transforms the texture. However, it seems that my scaling isn't perfect, as the texture appears corrupted(?).

[image: uneven]

This is when the filters are set to `GL_NEAREST`. When set to `GL_LINEAR`, it comes out blurry, which I don't want either. This made me suspect it was improper scaling, adding on to the fact that `glGetError()` returns `GL_NO_ERROR`. That didn't make sense though, because I'm scaling it to be "pixel-perfect" with respect to the screen pixels and the bitmap pixels... (see below code)

Through extensive research and testing everything I could think of, I found out the root cause: when the width of the bitmap is uneven, the corruption occurs. When I add code to pad the bitmap when it's uneven...

[image: even]

The corruption fades and the texture renders perfectly! (Tested more than the above)

Why is this and how can I get around it?

*Texture creation code (excerpted):*

```
...
float vertices[] = {
    // positions   // texture coords
    1.0,   1.0,  1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
    1.0,  -1.0,  1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
    -1.0, -1.0,  0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
    -1.0,  1.0,  0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3
};

// `VA`, `VB`, `EB`, and `TX` are class variables
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VA);
glGenBuffers(1, &VB);
glGenBuffers(1, &EB);
glGenTextures(1, &TX);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TX);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

// Sharp, easier to tell when texture is rendering incorrectly
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
// Blurry
// glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glBindVertexArray(VA);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VB);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EB);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

constexpr int stride = 4 * sizeof(float);

// position attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// texture coord attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// `shader` is a shader program for the below shaders
glUseProgram(shader);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "Tex"), 0);
...
```

*Texture loading code, called once per texture (excerpted):*

```
...
unsigned char *bitmap = loadImage(&width, &height,...);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TX);
// Before you ask: yes, the image is in RBGA
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap);
...
```

*Texture rendering code, called every frame (again, excerpted):*

```
...
glm::mat4 model(1.0f);

// Probally not relevent
const float xPos = (x + width / 2) / windowWidth * 2 - 1;
const float yPos = ((y + height / 2) / windowHeight * 2 - 1) * -1;
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(xPos, yPos, 0.0f));

model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3((float)width / windowWidth, (float)height / windowHeight, 0.0f));

// `modelLocation` was previously set to glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model")
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

glBindVertexArray(VA);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VB);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EB);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TX);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
...
```

*Vertex shader:*

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;

void main() {
    gl_Position = model * vec4(aPos, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

*Fragment shader:*

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D Tex;

void main() {
    FragColor = texture(Tex, TexCoord);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want pixel-exact texture mapping, it is not enough to scale your `m`x`n` texels big texture so that it will be mapped to an `m`x`n` pixel big rectangle on screen. You must also assure that the mapping will be correct at the sub-pixel level - i.e. that the texel centers are mapped to the corresponding pixel centers. In your case, you use the full `[0,1]` range as tex coords (which is fine), so your geometry must be mapped so that the vertices end up on pixel *corners* (such that it maps the corresponding texel corners directly onto them 1:1).

You have not exactly specified which types `width` and `height` have in this example, but the construct `(float)width / windowWidth` makes me assume that these are integral types. So let's do a simple example:

Let `x=0`, `width=3` and `windowWidth=10`. What happens is:

```
xPos = (0.0f + 3 / 2) / 10 * 2 - 1 = 1.0f / 10 * 2 - 1 = - 0.8f
```

The scale factor for the x dimension will be `0.3`, and the first row of your model matrix will end up as `0.3 0 0 -0.24`. When multiplied with your left and right points, you'll get `x_left = -0.54` and `x_right = 0.06`. The pixel borders in NDC would be at `{-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 10}` fo a 10 pixel wide viewport, so you are drawing not in a pixel-exact way.

Your translation simply doesn't mase sense for pixel-exact drawing, especially with the odd way of first translating and then scaling the resulting space.

Comment: I tried adding `0.5f` to `width` (and `height`) to get the pixel width to the "center"; it reduced the corruption, however not eliminating it. Am I doing this right? This happens when the translation is enabled or disabled.

Comment: @Kein no, your scaling with the actual pixel width is correct - in my example `x_right - x_left` evaluates to `0.6` which are exactly 3 pixels width. The only thing which is off is your translation